# How to pass validation errors to view without redirect in Laravel

Tags: validation, view, laravel

How can i pass validation errors directly to a View without a redirect in Laravel? 
I don't want to do that:

```
return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
```

but rather:

```
Input::flash(); // for repopulating fields
Validator::flash(); // this doesn't exist    
return View::make('fragments/login_ajax');
```

Or another more concise direct generation of a view without a redirect. Optimal would be something like that, but that doesn't work:

```
return View::make('fragments/login_ajax')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
```

The reason is, that this is the answer to an ajax based login. Redirecting to another method only used to display the same view deems unneccessary.

Cheers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Real answer: 
this is not an issue that is worth spending time on.  It is an architecture problem.

Possible Solution to your situation (not recommended):
Make auth a new route and have it return json of errors/messages.  Then have JS deal with the errors / messages / logic.

Comment: Ok thanks, let's go for the architecture change. I got a working solution with this approach: post method only handles the logic, then it redirects (with errors and input) to the get Method which also creates the non ajax login form. This get methods checks for Request::ajax() and decides whether to return the full login form or only the ajax snippet. Do you consider this to be a better approach?

Answer (score 2):

Though agreeing it is a bad idea to do this, you can use `View::share()` to share the errors to all the views.

`\View::share('errors', $errors);`

Answer (score 0):

Use below solution.

Controller:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), 
                             [
                                'class_id' => 'required|numeric|not_in:0',
                                'batch_id' => 'required|numeric|not_in:0',
                                'student_id' => 'required|numeric|not_in:0'
                             ]);
$this->viewData['errors'] = $validator->errors();
```

View File:

```
{!! Form::label('class_id','Student Class') !!}
{!! Form::select('class_id', array(), 0, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 
'class_id']) !!}{!! $errors->first('class_id', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>')!!}
```